# Mostrar contenido de solo un artículo, no de todos, con Flutter

Tags: flutter

Conecté una api a mi app de Flutter. Lo que intento es que al presionar UNA imagen (tengo un `listview` para que me aparezcan todas las imágenes) y me mande a *page2* (eso ya lo hace), me aparezca el contenido(content) de este. Lo que no logro es que solo me aparezca la info de solo esa imagen ya que el `listview` hace que me aparezca el contenido de todos los artículos que me aparecen en la api como obvio una lista. ¿Cómo hago que me aparezca uno solo?

```
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _Page2State createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  Future<NewsModel> _newsModel;

 @override
  void initState() {
    _newsModel = API_Manager().getNews();
    super.initState();
  }


    


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('News App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<NewsModel>(
          future: _newsModel,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var article = snapshot.data.articles[index];
                // var formattedTime = DateFormat('dd MMM - HH:mm')
                //  .format(article.publishedAt);
                return Container(
                  child: Text(
                    article.content,
                  ),
                );
              });
            } else
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: puedes mostrar como seleccionas la imagen ?, en teoría deberías mandar `arguments` a tu page2

Comment: Hola , puse en otro comentario el codigo , es desde donde esta mi onTap

Comment: por favor [edit] tu pregunta y agrega el código de tu `onTap`, o la nueva explicación que quieras dar.

Answer (score 0):

Me equivoque al decir que presionaba la imagen , es al presionar el container que contiene una imagen ,titulo,descripcion..

````
  Future<NewsModel> _newsModel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _newsModel = API_Manager().getNews();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('News App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<NewsModel>(
          future: _newsModel,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.articles.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var article = snapshot.data.articles[index];
                    var formattedTime = DateFormat('dd MMM - HH:mm')
                        .format(article.publishedAt);
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 100,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Card(
                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                              ),
                              child: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio: 1,
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    article.urlToImage,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  )),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 16),
                            Flexible(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(formattedTime),
                                  Text(
                                    article.title,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    article.description,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            } else
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Es una respuesta o parte de tu pregunta?